# How do I schedule database backups in heroku?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I am following the [directions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#scheduling-backups) on Heroku for scheduling backups of my postgres database on my django app.

It says to run the command

```
heroku pg:backups schedule DATABASE_URL --at '02:00 America/Los_Angeles' --app sushi.
```

Now lets suppose my app is called fancy-forest-9201. Obviously I'll replace the app "sushi" with that and run

```
heroku pg:backups schedule DATABASE_URL --at '02:00 America/Los_Angeles' --app fancy-forest-9201
```

Do I literally type that? Or am I supposed to replace DATABASE_URL with some other variable such as a real URL or environment variable name. If so, where do I get that URL? Or should I include a dollar sign in front of DATABASE_URL (that is, fetch it from the environment).

How can I be sure that it has run? When I run `heroku pg:backups --app fancy-forest-9201` I see this

=== Backups
ID    Backup Time                Status                               Size    Database

---

b007  2015-12-21 19:34:49 +0000  Completed 2015-12-21 19:34:50 +0000  43.3kB  DATABASE

a006  2015-12-21 19:14:39 +0000  Completed 2015-12-21 19:14:42 +0000  43.3kB  DATABASE

b005  2015-12-21 18:00:18 +0000  Completed 2015-12-21 18:00:20 +0000  43.3kB  DATABASE

Those are my manual backups. Am I right in assuming that when the automated backup runs, I should see one starting with b008?

Answer (score 1):

Use the literal string: `DATABASE_URL`.

`DATABASE_URL` is the config var name, so as long as that is what `heroku config` shows as the key for your database url, then you'll be fine using that.

Yes, the automated and manual backups will be differentiated by their prefix.

Comment: Thanks. That appears to work. I see one named a008 for which I assume 'a' indicates automated. The backup time time appears to differ from the time I requested by about 28 minutes but that isn't really a problem for me.